# In k8s, how to deploy a pod in a replication controller?

Tags: kubernetes

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.16.0
commit: 9f1e482427589ff8451c4723b6ba53bb9742fbb1

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c", GitCommit:"d1db3c46e55f95d6a7d3e5578689371318f95ff9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-20T22:21:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:51:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm new to kubernetes.

I'm trying to follow the examples in the book "Kubernetes in Action" which was written 2-3 yeas back so I'm aware that the info in it is outdated now.

When I run this command, I get the following output.

```
$ kubectl run kubia --image=myrepo/kubia --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
Flag --generator has been deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
pod/kubia created
```

The pod runs, but there supposedly should be a replication controller created, but there's not.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia   1/1     Running   0          3m27s
$ kubectl get rc
No resources found in default namespace.
```

All the subsequent commands depend on the replication controller being created, like the following

```
$ kubectl scale rc kubia --replicas=3
```

So how can I create a replication controller and have it control the pod? Or what is the alternative to creating a replication controller so I can scale the pod?

I'm aware that I can write configuration files instead of using the CLI, but I'm following the book for now.

Comment: Create a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

Comment: As said above you need to create a deployment for replication. `kubectl run` will only create a pod. `kubectl run -h` returns `Create and run a particular image in a pod.`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, put an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Turing85's comment, here's what I had to do. I aliased kubectl to k.

```
$ k create deploy kubia-deploy --image=myrepo/kubia
deployment.apps/kubia-deploy created

$ k get deploy
NAME           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubia-deploy   1/1     1            1           8s

$ k scale deploy kubia-deploy --replicas=3
deployment.apps/kubia-deploy scaled

$ k get po
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia-deploy-68675b44f6-52rbb   1/1     Running   0          3m45s
kubia-deploy-68675b44f6-ddt8g   1/1     Running   0          3m45s
kubia-deploy-68675b44f6-np624   1/1     Running   0          4m42s

$ k expose deploy kubia-deploy --type=LoadBalancer --name kubia-http --port=8080
service/kubia-http exposed
```